# Argumen out of range Exception was unhandled

Tags: c#

got stuck in here every time i try to click the EditTool
[Click-Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ucdE.jpg)

Comment: I guess you didn't read what error you have. Please read all provided information: *"Value '0' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'Minimum' and 'Maximum'"*

Comment: i had changed the min value to -10 and got the same error with "Value '-10' is not valid for 'Value'. maybe with convert string to int ?

Comment: I do not know what type of combobox you are using but it seems the value is already is of `int` type. Do not know why you converting it at all.

Comment: do you have time to check that ?
i can send it to you if you want to checking

Comment: Ah sorry its numericupdown control not combobox. But then additional thing. Do you really want to use [-- before operand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc3z3k8c.aspx)?

Comment: if not using -- before operand the value fill the second field not the first field like copying

Comment: Sorry but no, SO is not check/debug my code service. Please read what type of questions to [avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [how to ask good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like BossSnNumUD Has Minimum And Maximum Values so when you do
[image]

you are setting the value to 0 ,and ArgumentOutOfRangeExeption is thrown .
Because it's out of the range.

Comment: yes BossSnNumUD has min = 1 and max = 13 ,, no luck for me i though XD

Comment: do you have a time to checking this ? i can send it to you

Comment: I suggest to move this  code  --this.BossSnNumUD.Value   to variable ,and see what line causes the exception.So you will be able to determine if the problem is with convert or with the range of the Value .

Comment: solve that but now i got error again at

'numArray2[0] = checked ((int) byFileByte[index1 + 1] << 8 + (int) byFileByte[index1]);'

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @YogiSogekingINA Please accept answer if it was useful for your INITIAL question. Try to solve additional problems by your self and after you struggle once again -fill new question.

Comment: @Reniuz yes sure and thanks for your help ;) 
btw your tips very help me XD
changing (--this.BossSnNumUD.Value) to (this.BossSnNumUD.Value) - 1